# How to properly restart Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I haven't found any indication about how to completely restart hyperledger fabric and all the docker containers after rebooting the computer.

In particular, I have this containers:

```
$ docker container ls -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                            NAMES
8fe26f6bf531        hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1                                                                                        "peer node start"        41 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes             0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
0caca897250f        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1                                                                                     "orderer"                41 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes             0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
a3addacf7808        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10                                                                                    "tini -- /docker-ent…"   41 minutes ago      Up 41 minutes             4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
1c699bc55cbf        hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.1                                                                                          "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   41 minutes ago      Up 41 minutes             0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
a3214a02a0e5        localhost/composer-rest-server                                                                                       "pm2-docker composer…"   17 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                                                    rest
30c1e5ace414        mongo                                                                                                                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                                                    mongo
b7baef0aa3c7        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1-6695b9314667cc296171c0da511644e9011aa9a3ba0f6e759aca9e32e458803c   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   17 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                                                    dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1
```

running the command `./startFabric.sh` only the first four containers are started.

How can I restart also the last three containers to have a system running like before rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly ./stopFabric followed by ./teardownFabric before using ./startFabric?

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see, u r working on windows, in order to restart ur docker and network, u can't use simple commands like in Ubuntu, before restarting ur docker containers, stop all running containers, remove them, prune the volume of docker, then restart ur docker, finally, u can re-run the Hyperledger Network:

1)Stop running containers, remove them, prune volume:

```
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker volume prune
```

2)Restart ur docker, for this go to the docker icon on the right bottom of the desktop, right click, then "restart":

[image]

3)Finally, re-run the network:

```
$./startFabric.sh
```

!!!=>Solution for the Ubuntu case:

```
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$sudo systemctl restart docker
$./startFabric.sh
```

Comment: no commands you provide except `docker volume prune` will work on windows ....and how do you know the OP is working on windows?

Comment: i can't see wht u r trying to say, but in my statement, i wanted to say, u can't simply restart docker with command line!

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (as suggested from the Hyperledger Composer documentation)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, its very well the case that your network i stopped just because some of the containers exited. Now to fully recover the whole thing just use ./stopFabric.sh and then check if all containers are deleted by using

```
docker ps -a
```

Then you can again start your network by using ./startFabric.sh and then check if all the containers are working fine by using

```
docker ps -a
```